# Shell Script to Check for Proper Case Sentence

Tags: shell, sh

Can anyone help me with a regex to check whether all words in a sentence are in proper case i.e. begin with a uppercase letter?

```
#!/bin/sh

SENTENCE="Blah blah blah"

PROPER_CASE_REGEX="\b^AZ*\b"  # <---- Here's where I need help please

if [[ ${SENTENCE} =~ $PROPER_CASE_REGEX ]];
then
    echo "Sentence IS proper case"
elif
then
    echo "Sentence is NOT proper case"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in BASH (not in bourne shell) to check whether a sentence has all words starting with uppercase letters:

```
^([A-Z][[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]*)+$
```

**Testing:**

```
re='^([A-Z][^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*)+$'

sentence="Blah Blah Blah"    
[[ "$sentence" =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "no match"
matched

sentence="Blah Blah blah"
[[ "$sentence" =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "no match"
no match
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY2pS7/2)

Comment: If you only want to do it in `sh` not `bash` then use same regex using `expr` command.

Comment: This is nearly perfect thank you however "Paddy O'Shea" or "Shaun Peters-Wensley" are NOT considered proper case, how might I resolve this?  Assume the [:allnum:] needs to include ' and -?

Comment: In that case use `re='^([A-Z][^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*)+$'`